# react - accessing DOM without breaking encapsulation

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a cannonical way of going about doing something like the following without breaking encapsulation?

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

class Dashboard extends Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);

        this.setRef = ::this.setRef;
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        const node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.someRef);
        const newHeight = window.innerHeight - node.offsetTop - 30;
        node.style.maxHeight = `${newHeight}px`;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="some-element-id" ref={this.setRef}>
            </div>
        );
    }

    setRef(ref) {
        this.someRef= ref;
    }
}
```

[`ReactDOM.findDOMNode`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#reactdom.finddomnode) seems to be the suggested way of going about this, but this still breaks encapsulation and the documentation has a big red flag to this extent.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "breaks encapsulation"? What are your concerns exactly? On a high-level, you're right, you should be careful about imperatively manipulating the DOM within a React component, but what are your concerns specifically?

Comment: I mean that React provides a construct that abstracts the DOM away from you and you're "reaching outside" of that very construct to interact with the DOM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the component "state" to set the [style property](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html) of the react element, so you only access the "real" DOM node to calculate the height and then you update the state, re-rendering the component. The react component now has the same information as the real DOM node, so it shouldn't be breaking encapsulation.

Using vanilla JS to provide an example:

```
var Component = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
    return {
        style: {},
    }
  },
  componentDidMount: function(){
    var node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
    var newHeight = window.innerHeight - node.offsetTop - 30;
    this.setState({style: {backgroundColor: '#bbb', height: newHeight.toString() + 'px' }});
  },
  render: function(){
    return React.createElement('div', {style: this.state.style}, 'Height: ' + this.state.style.height);
  },
});
```

You can see it running in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wkcuqs21/).

Comment: also I should add that just because the react component has the same information as the real DOM node I'm not sure that means it's not breaking encapsulation (especially since I'm also using `window` here) - under the hood I don't know that DOM node is being "safely" exposed through the Component - but I see what you're getting after *I think* -> so long as you use the DOM for read-only purposes and keep the component state in sync you are probably safe from unintended side effects

Comment: also if you're using the react eslint plugin and get an error here you should be okay to disable it so long as you know what you're doing: https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/554

Answer (score 2):

While this technically "breaks encapsulation" in the general sense, if there is no other way to do it (and in this case there is not), then using findDOMNode is your only choice and it is the correct one.

If you find yourself using it repeatedly, you should create a wrapper component to encapsulate that behavior.